# R highchart: create group by linetype

Tags: r, highcharts

I am trying to convert a plot I did in ggplot2 into an interactive highcharts plot in R. The code I used in ggplot2 is below.

```
projection_LTV_conversion%>%
      ggplot(aes(x = period, y = projection, color = cohort, linetype = is_proj))+
      geom_line()
```

What is very practical in ggplot2 is I can group my data on two different aspects: per color and per linetype. I have tried to replicate that behavior in highcharter but did not manage to find how I could do it. For instance, the code below gives me an error.

```
hchart(object = projection_LTV_conversion,
       type = "line",
       mapping = hcaes(x = period, y = projection, group = c(cohort, is_proj)))
```

Basically, the issue is the group argument only accepts one argument. Does anyone have a solution to replicate these ggplot2 functionalities?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
data("diamonds")
diamonds%>%
  head(100)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = price, y = carat, color = clarity, size = cut))+
  geom_point()
```

In that example, we get two legends. One based on the color and a second on the size.

At the moment, I did not find a way to reproduce this in highcharters. The closer I got there:

```
hchart(object = diamonds%>%head(100),
       type = "scatter",
       mapping = hcaes(x = price, y = carat, group = clarity))
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Hello @Quinten,
I cannot share this data online but I have added a reproducible example. It is not with linetype, but with size instead, but the idea is exactly the same.